# Apache Timezone 'Internal' but correctly 'External' from command line PHP script

Tags: php, apache, timezone

from Apache phpinfo

```
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Europe/London
```

but is correct from command line

```
php  -i | grep -i timezone
```

gives:

```
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 2011.14
Timezone Database => external
Default timezone => Europe/London
date.timezone => Europe/London => Europe/London
Alternative Timezone Database => enabled
Timezone Database Version => 2011.14
```

*setting in php.ini*

```
extension=timezonedb.so
```

*Centos 5.7 x64*

*Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)*

*PHP 5.3.3*

Any clues?

Comment: 2 `php.ini` files - 1 for the web server and 1 for the command line ... search for `php.ini` files on your system

Comment: Hi sadly only one (locate php.ini)

Comment: Try `find /etc -name php*.ini -print` as `locate` doesn't traverse the filesystem.

Comment: @crontab only one is found > find / -name php\\*.ini -print outputs
/etc/php.ini

Comment: Hi what solved it for me:- yum update tzdata

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me  :- from

[Server Fault: updating-systems-olson-timezone-database-version](https://serverfault.com/questions/192858/updating-systems-olson-timezone-database-version)

yum update tzdata

Red Herring 1

BTW phpinfo still displaying the same info but Timezone data now the same for the same script from from the CLI and via apache

Red Herring 2

Thinking that Apache was accessing a different PHP